# android app doesn't go on after while

Tags: android

in my android app I have got a simple if check:

```
if (manual == true) {


       ArrayList<String> ACList = new ArrayList<>()
       String[] ACString = SplitString.split(";");

       int x = 0;
       while (x < ACString.length) {
          Log.e("-->", ""+x);

         String[] DataSplit = ACString[x].split(",");

          if (!ACList.contains(DataSplit[1])) {
              Log.e("-->", "NEW: "+DataSplit[1]);
              ACList.add(x,DataSplit[1]);
          }
          x++;
       }

       Log.e("-->", "2");
       intent.putExtra("A", true);
       Log.e("-->", "3");
       startActivity(intent);
       Log.e("-->", "4");
}
```

Problem is:

and 4 times the log of value x (Because the length of ACString is 4

But i dont get Log 2,3 and 4.
Any Ideas?

**UPDATE**

Log of the Part if (!ACList.contains...)

```
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: Value 1
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: NEW: Value 1
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: Value 2
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: NEW: Value 2
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: Value 1
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: Value 2
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: Value 3
01-12 14:57:18.791 E: NEW: Value 3
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your snippet? What is intent? It is never defined.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);

Answer (score 1):

Unless an exception is triggered in "// DO SOMETHING" and caught elsewhere, your issue seems to be that "// DO SOMETHING" never returns on the 4th loop.
Two easy way to know if it's that:

- Add a breakpoint on "x++;" and check you reach this point on the 4th loop, then continue step by step to confirm you leave the loop and go to "Log.e("-->", "2");"
- Or, just add a log just after "// DO SOMETHING" and check the log appears when x equals 3 (it should leave the loop just after).

Comment: LOG: ACString.length = 5;  And i have set an Log before x++; OUTPUT 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 - All correct but i don't get any logs after while

Comment: Please look at my first post, i add the real code to the part of //DO SOMETHING. If i remove the part if (!ACList.contains...), the Logs after while will be shown. where is my mistake?